# Does Whatsapp use wi-fi where possible?

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, text-messaging

I just got Whatsapp on the new iPhone 5. I know it uses the data plan to send messages, but I'm wondering if it will use WiFi instead where possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're connected to a WiFi, all of your apps that require internet usage will automatically use the WiFi connection instead, so yes of course WhatsApp will use WiFi if you're connected to one.

You shouldn't find your data usage going up if you're connected to WiFi.